# Pass php variable in bar graph with highcharts

Tags: php, mysql, highcharts

I have a bar graph made with highcharts that display properly, data are from mysql table. I would like to pass value i mean : **($category['data'][] = $r['Assign_To'])** in each bar as variable so that when i click on a bar this value contained in variable is taken  to a new page in order to use it in that page. The exemple given in  highcharts website doesn't fit me because i use data from table.

1- this is the graph

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
        var options = {
            chart: {
                renderTo: 'container',
                type: 'bar'
            },
            title: {
                text: 'EOP Postings Issues Chart',
                x: -20 //center
            },

             credits: {
        enabled: false
    },
            xAxis: {
                categories: []
            },
            yAxis: {
                min: 0,
                title: {
                    text: 'Requests'
                },
             },

            legend: {
                layout: 'vertical',
                align: 'right',
                verticalAlign: 'top',
                x: -10,
                y: 100,
                borderWidth: 0
            }, 

            series: []
        }

        $.getJSON("DataEobChart.php", function(json) {
            options.xAxis.categories = json[0]['data'];
            options.series[0] = json[1];

            chart = new Highcharts.Chart(options);
        });
    });
```

2. DataEobChart.php

   ```
    $dbc = @mysqli_connect('', '', '', '');
   $query = mysqli_query($dbc, "select *, count(Assign_To) as count,Assign_To from claims_follow_up.eob_posting where  Status='open'  group by Assign_To order by count desc");
    $category = array();
     $category['name'] = 'Month';
     $series1 = array();
     $series1['name'] = 'Number of issues assigned';
     while($r = mysqli_fetch_array($query)) {
     $category['data'][] = $r['Assign_To'];
    $series1['data'][] = $r['count'];

      }
    $result = array();
     array_push($result,$category);
      array_push($result,$series1);
   print json_encode($result, JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK);
    mysqli_close($dbc);
   ```

Comment: Can you provide an example of the JSON that is generated by your PHP file?  Then it'll be easier to work with the HighChart code so it can use the JSON data.

Comment: DataEobChart.php is the json

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a new section to your HighCharts definition called `plotOptions` containing this code:

```
        plotOptions: {
            series: {
                cursor: 'pointer',
                point: {
                    events: {
                        click: function (event) {
                            var index = event.point.index;
                            var Assign_To = options.xAxis.categories[index];
                            alert(Assign_To);
                            location.href = "NewPage.php?AssignTo=" + Assign_To;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        },
```

This provides a click event handler which will figure out which `options.xAxis.categories[]` item to use based on which bar was clicked.  It will then alert the result and then take the user to a page called `NewPage.php` with a request string called `AssignTo`.

Comment: this new section put me on the way to do it. There is only one issue when i click on bar i go to NewPage but the variable is not kept. Here is the url after clicking: http://localhost/bposssss/NewPage?AssignTo=undefined

Comment: You'll need to help me debug this.  First, I fixed a small problem that prevented it from showing the value with the `alert()`.  Try this new code.  Also, checked the results of the debug console.  Perhaps something is wrong with the `options.xAxis.categories[index]`.  Play around with the console.log and tell me what you find.

Comment: Then play with the console.log.  Change it to `console.log(options)`.  Do you see what you expect to see?  If you drill down, can you find the data you want?  Probably the path to the data you want isn't correct.  That's what I mean... help me debug.  Sorry, but I can't do it for you.

Comment: Sorry if i ask this question, can u show me how to use console.log ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/121297/discussion-between-dr-cool-and-diasline).